# xcode 6 beta 4 new Swift issues with NS_ENUM defined in Objective C

Tags: swift, xcode6

Just started to use Xcode6 beta 4 and have come up against an issue that was not there before. I define my NS_ENUM in my objective-c as follows:

```
typedef NS_ENUM( NSInteger, ToolbarType ) {
   tb_closed_k = 0,
   tb_text_k = 10,
   tb_shape_k,
   tb_undefined_k
```

};

Then in my swift code i want to set a variable to one of these values:

```
var test = ToolbarType. tb_undefined_k
```

This was working without issues in beta 3 but now I get an error that :

```
'ToolbarType' does not have a member named 'var test = ToolbarType. tb_undefined_k'
```

After investigating further, if I type the enum type followed by a ., auto completion shows me the options and it suggests the value to be:

```
ToolbarType.b_undefined_k
```

is seems very odd. Is this a bug or some kind of naming convention? I am afraid if I use these suggested values, in the next release they all become broken.

Any suggestions. Thanks.

Reza

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Your code compiles without errors in my Xcode 6 beta 4.

Comment: Martin you are right as my example was a simplified version, I have updated this with the real example and more information

Answer (score 0):

After playing around I found that if I added a value to the end of the enum that did not in anyway conform to the naming convention of the values that proceeded it then the error would go away. In fact I just added "dummy" to the end my list of enums and it all started to work